# C++ iterate over subvectors of size N

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have an input vector which can be of any size. What I want is to divide this vector into vectors of size 64 each and do something. The input vector's size should not necessarily be of size multiple to 64.

So let's say I have a vector of size 200, then I should divide it into 3 vectors of size 64 and 1 vector of size 8.

What I thought of so far is the following:

```
vector<double> inputVector;
vector<vector<double>> resultVector;

UInt16 length = inputVector.size();
int div = (length % 64) == 0 ? length / 64 : (length / 64) + 1;

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < div; i++) {
    vector<double> current
    for (int k = 0; k < 64; k++) {
        current.push_back(inputVector[j]);
       if (j++ >= length) break;
    }
    resultVector.push_back(current);
    if (j >= length) break;
}
```

I am sure there would be a better way of doing so but I could't find any example

Comment: You could use vector range constructor/assign ((2) from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign ), but you might not consider that better.

Comment: Do you need a copy of the input data in the result vector?

Comment: @florestan I need the result vector have sub-vectors of the input vector

Comment: Create a vector of pointers, now use `new` to allocate a space for new vector and copy the values. Now go to next pointer in the vector and do it for next part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use iterators to create a subvector:

```
vector<double> inputVector;
vector<vector<double>> resultVector;

for (auto it = inputVector.cbegin(), e = inputVector.cend(); it != inputVector.cend(); it = e) {
    e = it + std::min<std::size_t>(inputVector.cend() - it, 64);
    resultVector.emplace_back(it, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is just for each element push_back to some vector, keep track of them, and if the chunk size is reached then "flush" them to the output vector:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> devide(const std::vector<T>& v, size_t chunk) {
    // iterative algorithm
    std::vector<T> tmp;
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;
    size_t cnt = 0;
    for (auto&& i : v) {
        tmp.push_back(i);
        ++cnt;
        if (cnt == chunk) {
             cnt = 0;
             ret.push_back(tmp);
             tmp.clear();
        }
    }
    if (cnt != 0) {
        ret.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

but that iterative approach is not optimal - we could copy chunks of memory. So iterate over vector and copy up to chunk count of elements each loop - and copy less on the last loop.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> devide2(const std::vector<T>& v, size_t chunk) {
    // chunk algorithm
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;
    const auto max = v.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max; ) {
        const size_t chunkend = std::min(i + chunk, max);
        ret.emplace_back(v.begin() + i, v.begin() + chunkend);
        i = chunkend;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

[Tested on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jzW8r3).

Answer (score 0):

More in STL style:

```
void even_slice(In b, In e, size_t n, F f)
{
    while(std::distance(b, e) >= n) {
        f(b, b + n);
        b = b + n;
    }
    if (b != e) {
        f(b, e);
    }
}

template<typename In, typename Out>
Out even_slice_to_vetors(In b, In e, size_t n, Out out)
{
    using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<In>::value_type;
    using ItemResult = std::vector<ValueType>;
    even_slice(b, e, n, [&out](auto x, auto y) { *out++ = ItemResult{x, y}; });
    return out;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zn9Ex1

Answer (score 0):

Note that you know exactly how many subvectors have the wanted maximum size:

```
template<typename It>
auto subdivide_in_chunks(It first, It last, size_t chunk_size) {
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
    size_t size{ std::distance(first, last) / chunk_size };
    std::vector<std::vector<value_type>> ret;
    ret.reserve(size);
    auto last_chunk = std::next(first, size * chunk_size);
    while ( first != last_chunk ) {
        auto next = std::next(first, chunk_size);    
        ret.emplace_back(first, next);
        first = next;
    }
    ret.emplace_back(first, last);  // This is the last, shorter one. 
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With range-v3, you could simply write:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto resultVector = inputVector 
                  | rv::chunk(64) 
                  | rs::to<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8vrhqb).